# Ubuntu 20.04: suspend disk encryption to install firmware update?

Tags: suspend, encryption, thinkpad, firmware

I have received in ubuntu software an update for the Intel platform (2021.2 Release). I am running ubuntu 20.04 on a ThinkPad Carbon X1 9thGen with full disk encryption activated during installation.

Now the firmware update contains the note "*Please suspend or disable disk encryption tool prior to update*". Is that really necessary? And if so, how can I suspend the disk encryption tool?

To complete the post: I have only Ubuntu installed and the boot partitions are NOT encrypted, only the main partition is.

I could not find much info on the web about this issue.

Comment: Hello. If it tells you it is necessary it is. How would anyone on this Ubuntu OS support site. Know anything about your Intel hardware? You can run it before you stop the service but I hope you have good backups and are prepared to reinstall. BTW Any and all questions need to have the version of Ubuntu in the question.

Comment: Does your system have a dual-boot configuration? Or is Ubuntu the only operating system? I seem to remember that I've encountered this and rolled the dice and ignored it (because you can't just disable encryption like that). In my case, everything completed successfully, but my boot was not encrypted due to dual-boot config.

Comment: I have only Ubuntu installed, no dual-boot.  However I checked and the boot partitions (/boot and /boot_efi)  are not encrypted, only the root partition is, with LUKS Encryption V2. So maybe it is fine to upgrade the firmware (?), since maybe it is only the boot partition interested by a firmware update.

Comment: I have a 5th generation Carbon X1 with full disk encryption (using ZFS). The firmware updates install fine 

Comment: Just a guess but have you looked through the running services? `systemctl status`  Will show them all. Then if you find it, stop it. `systemctl stop servicename.service`

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed the firmware update. I did it by installing the update from the ubuntu software app and then rebooting. Probably the warning note is relevant if you have encrypted also the boot partition(s).

Anyway, I suggest doing a full backup before (as I did).